# Increment Time for every 10 Row using update in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

need an mysql update query to increment time for every 10 row by 6 seconds with the first entry time starting from a specific date-time...

lets say `2015-12-08 00:00:00` is the timestamp i want for the first 10  entries, 
next 10 entries should get
       `2015-12-08 00:00:06` ,

then the next 10-

```
2015-12-08 00:00:12
```

the next 10

```
2015-12-08 00:00:18
```

...and so on till last entry, the time has to increment by 6 seconds and accordingly the `minutes` and `hours` as it increases till the last entry

any idea how to make an update query for that?

PS: i dont have a unique id or value in the table in any column, the values may repeat. I would prefer an Update statement to use as i may have to change for other tables too,rather than triggers or Store procedure. I am using MySQL v7.02 SQLyog Enterprise

Comment: There is no real concept of "the next 10" internally in a MySQL database.  Is there _anything_ you can use to order?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i do have another date field through which i can order the table..lets say `start_time`

Comment: Even if someone gives you a query, you still will face the problem of maintaining the table.  What will happen as new records are added later on?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i was thinking of updating it everytime with the query. As i may not get new data in the table regularly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope the following statement can help:

```
select
 @row_n := @row_n + 1 as row_no
, case when MOD(@row_n,10) =0 then @time:= ADDTIME(@time,'00:06') else @time end
  from [your_table]
   JOIN  (SELECT @row_n := 0) r 
   JOIN  (SELECT @time := now()) t
```

and example of update statement:

```
update tableA set dateCol=nestedTable.colB
from (
  select
   tableB.[some key]
 ,  @row_n := @row_n + 1 as row_no
 , (case when MOD(@row_n,10) =0 then @time:= ADDTIME(@time,'00:06') else @time end ) as colB
  from tableB
   JOIN  (SELECT @row_n := 0) r 
   JOIN  (SELECT @time := now()) t
 ) nestedTable
 where tableA.[some key] = nestedTable.[some key]
```

Comment: Replace now() with '2015-12-08 00:00:12'

Comment: so for update  it would it be like: `Update Table_Name set Date_Column= select dt from (select
 @row_n := @row_n + 1 as row_no
, case when MOD(@row_n,10) =0 then @time:= ADDTIME(@time,'00:06') else @time end as dt
  from [your_table]
   JOIN  (SELECT @row_n := 0) r 
   JOIN  (SELECT @time := '2015-12-08 00:00:00') t)`

Comment: You have to define the matching key between [Table_Name] and [your_table], for example:

Comment: i m defining same tableName for  [Table_Name] and [your_table], but it is giving : `Error Code : 1242
Subquery returns more than 1 row`                                                              I used following Update Query: `update `Table_Name` set Date_Column= (select dt from (select @row_n := @row_n + 1 as row_no , case when MOD(@row_n,10) =0 then @time:= ADDTIME(@time,'00:06') else @time end as dt from `Table_Name` JOIN (SELECT @row_n := 0) r JOIN (SELECT @time := '2015-12-08 00:00:00') t1)  t2)`

Comment: You have to define the matching key between [Table_Name] and [your_table], for example:
`update tableA set dateCol=nestedTable.colB
from (
  select
   tableB.[some key]
 ,  @row_n := @row_n + 1 as row_no
 , (case when MOD(@row_n,10) =0 then @time:= ADDTIME(@time,'00:06') else @time end ) as colB
  from tableB
   JOIN  (SELECT @row_n := 0) r 
   JOIN  (SELECT @time := now()) t
 ) nestedTable
 where tableA.[some key] = nestedTable.[some key]`
be sure the mapping is one to one, otherwise, your update query cannot get a correct result every time.

Comment: You can try to add 'order by' to the nestedTable to make your result more accurate.

Comment: i m accepting ur query as answer but also can i use the same query for increasing time in each entry/row instead of every 10 entries?

Comment: Yes, you can change of MOD parameter rather than 10, for example:

`MOD(@row_n, 5)
--increment time for every 5 entries`